# How to let twisted print the exact positions of unhandled errors

Tags: python, twisted

I am writing a simple server program. They will be inevitable typos and other errors in fresh code, and usually the python interpreter will print a ValueError/AttributeError traceback and exit. The traceback can point to the exact position of the error. However under the twisted framework, these errors are not printed. Like in the following example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, task
#from twisted.internet.defer import setDebugging
#setDebugging(True)

class MyProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            set_position(int(data))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clientConnectionMade(self)
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clientConnectionLost(self)

class MyFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = MyProtocol
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []
        self.lc = task.LoopingCall(self.announce)
        self.lc.start(1)

    def announce(self):
        pos = A_GREAT_TYPO_HERE()
        for client in self.clients:
            client.transport.write("Posiiton is {0}\n".format(pos).encode('utf-8'))

    def clientConnectionMade(self, client):
        self.clients.append(client)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, client):
        self.clients.remove(client)

def get_position():
    return position[0]

def set_position(pos):
    position[0] = pos

def main():
    global position
    position = [0]
    myfactory = MyFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(5362, myfactory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`A_GREAT_TYPO_HERE()` in MyFactory.announce is meant to be `get_position()`. But it is a typo.

And when the server is run, the terminal only outputs

`Unhandled error in Deferred:`

and nothing else. Even if I enable Defer debugging (uncomment the 2nd and 3rd line), the terminal outputs:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
(debug:  C: Deferred was created:
 C:  File "nodes/test.py", line 48, in <module>
 C:    main()
 C:  File "nodes/test.py", line 43, in main
 C:    myfactory = MyFactory()
 C:  File "nodes/test.py", line 21, in __init__
 C:    self.lc.start(1)
 C:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 189, in start
 C:    deferred = self._deferred = defer.Deferred()
 I: First Invoker was:
 I:  File "nodes/test.py", line 48, in <module>
 I:    main()
 I:  File "nodes/test.py", line 43, in main
 I:    myfactory = MyFactory()
 I:  File "nodes/test.py", line 21, in __init__
 I:    self.lc.start(1)
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 194, in start
 I:    self()
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 241, in __call__
 I:    d.addErrback(eb)
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 332, in addErrback
 I:    errbackKeywords=kw)
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 310, in addCallbacks
 I:    self._runCallbacks()
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
 I:    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
 I:  File "/home/sgsdxzy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 236, in eb
 I:    d.errback(failure)
)
```

It points the error as close as to `self.lc.start(1)`, but not `A_GREAT_TYPO_HERE()`. How can I debug my program so tracebacks can point to actual errors?

Comment: What version of Twisted are you using?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone it's 17.1.0, and python version is 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "C" and "I" lines you're seeing are due to the fact that you've enabled Deferred debugging.  The "C" lines give you the stack where the Deferred was created.  The "I" lines give you the stack where the Deferred was "invoked" (its `callback` or `errback` method was called).

Neither of those is what you're looking for, it seems.  If you want to see the stack associated with the `Failure` the Deferred has been fired with, the most straightforward solution is to make sure the `Failure` gets logged (and that you have a log observer so that you can actually see that log event).

You should add this to your `main`:

```
from sys import stdout
from twisted.logger import globalLogBeginner, textFileLogObserver
globalLogBeginner.beginLoggingTo([textFileLogObserver(stdout)])
```

This directs the log stream to stdout as text.  It is most likely sufficient to get you the information you want.  However, to be really safe, you also want to explicitly log failures instead of relying on the garbage collector to do it for you.  So you also want to change:

```
self.lc.start(1)
```

To:

```
# Module scope
from twisted.logger import Logger
logger = Logger()

...

# in __init__
d = self.lc.start(1)
d.addErrback(lambda f: logger.failure("Loop thing problem", f))
```

(Also you may want to consider taking this code out of `__init__` and putting it in `startFactory` instead; also consider not using a global reactor but instead pass it around as a parameter.)

This will give you output like:

```
2017-04-25T06:53:14-0400 [__main__.MyFactory#critical] Foo
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "debugging2.py", line 52, in main
            myfactory = MyFactory()
          File "debugging2.py", line 28, in __init__
            d = self.lc.start(1)
          File "/tmp/debugging/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 194, in start
            self()
          File "/tmp/debugging/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 239, in __call__
            d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/tmp/debugging/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
            result = f(*args, **kw)
          File "debugging2.py", line 32, in announce
            pos = A_GREAT_TYPO_HERE()
        exceptions.NameError: global name 'A_GREAT_TYPO_HERE' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks! The logger gives a lot of useful information, I will read the documentation about what it can offer.